# Wildcard version project dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild

Started using .net core. We have a lot of dlls in one folder containing whole software solution developed through years. Part of it start to use .net core. We used to release patches with just a few modified dlls to production environment with incremented version number. 
Apparently .net core is checking exact version of dependency dll, so when we release a patch with modified dll that .net core dll depends on, the application will not start writing error that Could not load file or assembly xxx.dll, version=1.2.3.4.

We use project dependencies. csproj file

Is it possible to override version checking to compare only first 2 digits of version or to skip version checking at all (we have own dll version checking system within the software)?

Comment: I can't reproduce the same issue in my side. In a solution i have two projects(one is .net core app, the other is .net core class library). I add project reference from app to library(1.0.0.0), build the solution and copy the output of .net core app to remote server. It works well of course, then I change the code in library and build it with version 2.0.0.0, copy the xxx.dll to server to replace the version-1.0.0.0 one, the application still works well and the code change takes effect obviously.

Comment: You can take a look at [AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Resolving](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext.resolving?view=netcore-2.2) event and the content of [.deps.json](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/12/21/netcore-primitives/) file, which is used by corehost.

Answer (score 1):

A strong reference (in a .csproj file) looks like this:

```
<Reference Include="MyLibrary, Version=2.9.4.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=85089178b9ac3181, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\lib\lib\net40\MyLibrary.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

When the DLL is missing then you will get that error you described.
To get away from that, you remove the version number altogether. This I call a weak reference:

```
<Reference Include="MyLibrary">
  <HintPath>..\lib\lib\net40\MyLibrary.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

If you control everything than a weak reference is fine. But be careful of these. MSBuild has the tendency to go looking throughout the entire computer. So best to have an accurate `<HintPath>`.

Comment: The problem is not with the dll references but with project references.

    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\MyProject\MyProject.csproj" />

Comment: ProjectReference's are strong by default, and there is no way around that. You have to stop using them, and go back to plain old, file references as I enumerated above. It kind of sucks for your use case. Perhaps this is the wrong solution, and you should just live it and fix your patch process instead. That seems more correct.